# Expected unqualified-id before 'double'/

Tags: c++, g++

I'm writing a program for a lab called Robot. When I compile it, I get this set of errors:

> Robot.cpp:43:13: error: expected unqualified-id before 'double'
>
> Robot.cpp:43:13: error: expected ')' before 'double'

The class is defined in the Robot.h header, and the code in the .cpp that's causing the problem looks like this:

```
/*
 * Name: Robot (constructor)
 *
 * Creates the robot with the given maximum speed.
 */

 Robot( double maxSpd ) 

 {

      MAX_SPEED = maxSpd;
      traveled = 0 ;
      elapsed = 0 ;
      x = 0 ;
      y = 0 ;

 }
```

I can't figure out why the errors are there... and I also don't know what that error even means. How would I solve it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid C++. Why do you have a semicolon after `maxSpd )`?

Comment: Is this in your class definition, or out of it?

Comment: Also, can you give us more context? This might be fine if it's in the context of a class, but I have a feeling that your scope is off.

Comment: Also, is `MAX_SPEED` constant? You *need* an initializer if you're initializing it, but you should put the others there as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. MAX_SPEED (and all other variables) are defined in the header, and MAX_SPEED is a constant. Should I add that to what I have here?

Also, I noticed that semi-colon the moment I entered the question... Ugh. Sorry. That was an error when I was copying the names of functions over from the header. Editing question now!

Comment: @FoolishOrpheus: as an aside, all-uppercase identifiers like "MAX_SPEED" are best avoided.  It's overwhelmingly common practice for preprocessor macro names to be upper case, which is a great reason to avoid upper case identifiers everywhere else: you don't want to find some header you're including defines MAX_SPEED and your code suddenly breaks.  Either mixed or lower case is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to recreate your errors.

<s>First of all, that semicolon after the signature has to go. It's declaring a function when you're trying to define one.</s>

```
Robot(double maxSpd) {...} //no semicolon
```

<s>Secondly</s>First of all, since this is outside of your class, you need to qualify it:

```
Robot::Robot(double maxSpd) {...}
```

Next, since `MAX_SPEED` is a constant, you need to put it in a member initializer:

```
Robot::Robot(double maxSpd)
    : MAX_SPEED(maxSpd) {...}
```

Finally, you should move the rest of your assignments to the initializer list as well (not necessary, but good to do), keeping in mind that they should be listed **in the order** they are declared in the class definition:

```
Robot::Robot(double maxSpd)
    : MAX_SPEED(maxSpd), traveled(0), elapsed(0), x(0), y(0) {
//body, which, from your example, would now be empty
}
```

Comment: The OP removed the semicolon after the signature (and the corresponding error message) after you posted your answer.

Comment: @chris Hey, I'm learning C++ here, and I have a question. I don't need to add Robot::Robot if I define the constructor inside of the class declaration, correct?

Comment: @Ken, You're correct. Outside, it needs it because it is no longer in the scope of `Robot`, so it needs the `Robot::` to get the scope right. The :: is called the scope resolution operator. If this was another function and you forgot it, all it would do is define a random function that has nothing to do with your class. If you then tried using the one in your class, you'd get a linker error because it was declared, but not defined. Since this is the constructor, though, you get a compiler error from having no return type.

Answer (score 2):

The possible problem could be that there is a semicolon before the open bracket. But without seeing the whole class, it would be difficult to say so.

If this code isn't inside the class declaration, you could possibly be missing a "Robot::" namespace specification before the "Robot()" constructor name.

Example:

```
Robot::Robot(double maxSpd)
{
   MAX_SPEED = maxSpd;
   traveled = 0;
   elapsed = 0;
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
}
```